# Changing ECW output colour for no input value areas

Tags: fme-form, ecw

I am attempting to convert a mosaic geodatabase raster to ECW using FME, but get black image output around the edge where there is no input value.

How do I change this from black?

Comment: Try the [rasterbandnodatasetter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/rasterbandnodatasetter.htm).

Answer (score 4):

So, what's happening is that pixels around the edge have the color black and full opacity, and aren't tagged as "nodata".

Either that wasn't the case in your source data, or you've lost your nodata value, or these pixels have been added during processing - it often happens in reprojection because the data subtly changes shape.

So, it's a simple problem with a bunch of solutions of varying complexity:

- Firstly, make sure the application you're using to view the output is rendering it correctly! Maybe the pixels are set to be transparent, but the app doesn't support transparency? It's happened.
- If the raster data is still rectangular, with a rectangular border of black pixels, use the Clipper transformer to trim off those unwanted pixels.
- If you just want to convert that border to white, then use a RasterExpressionEvaluator transformer, like so:

[image]

That says, if R,G,B values are all 0 (ie this is pure black) change them to 255 (white). So that'll change their color.

- You could make those pixels transparent. If you have an alpha band, then it's pretty similar to above, with a RasterExpressionEvaluator:

[image]

Not all formats support an alpha band, so you have to use the color technique sometimes anyway. If the format does support it, but you don't have that band, you can add one with a RasterBandAdder. Anyway, this time you don't change color, but you make black pixels invisible.

- Set a "nodata" value, that tells the viewer to ignore these pixels.

[image]

So you're telling the viewing tool to ignore those pixels, and not show them (as opposed to showing them invisibly, which sounds the same but is subtly different).

**The big problem is:** if you change the color or opacity or nodata status of cells with the value 0, then you're changing it for EVERY cell with that value, not just the borders.

So what I often do is change all incoming cells with 0 to 1. It doesn't make a visible difference to the output, but it frees up the 0 value to be our transparent/nodata values. I do that with a RasterExpressionEvalautor too:

[image]

The important part is that you have to do this BEFORE you introduce the black borders. Like above I do that before I reproject the data. That way I free up the zeros, before the border is introduced. Then I can clear it all, without affecting any other cells.

So there you go! Sorry if it turned out to be a long answer, but I like to be thorough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it still doesnt quite get the result i need, as i didnt include all of the relevant info in the question. I have an irregular shaped area of interest that was used to create a mosaic extract. making it ecw means that it completes the rectangle with no value pixels outside the irregular area. It appears that the program it is then being used in (Visum) doesn't support no value, and makes those pixels black. I have changed the image extract to rectangular, which has solved the no value problem in this case.